# MVC3 which is the correct attribute to only allow 1 or more roles to access a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, security

How do I lock down a controller class to only be accessible by one or more roles? I've tried using the `AuthorizeAttribute` in my second example, but it seems to force authorization to be requested, instead of granting access to the page.

```
[PrincipalPermission(SercurityAction.?????????)]
public class MySecuredController { ...
```

OR

```
[Authorize(Roles="MyRoleName")
public class MySecuredController { ...
```

OR

Am I completely wrong?

Whole script it is really just the MVC3 tutorial...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Permissions; 

namespace mvc3test.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles="taxpayer")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase dr405)
        {
            var saveLocation = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("\\"),"returns");
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(saveLocation);
            dr405.SaveAs(Path.Combine(saveLocation,User.Identity.Name) + ".xlsx");
            ViewBag.Message = String.Format("File name: {0}, {1}Kb Uploaded Successfully.",dr405.FileName,(int)dr405.ContentLength / 1024); 
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

when I run this the site logs me in after entering my credentials.  I know this because my name appears in the upper right corner of the screen.  But It just keeps taking my to the login screen over and over and over.

**Update**

So I added a watch to the `Redirect` Method in the `LogOn` Action for the value of `User.IsInRole("taxpayer")`  where `User.Identity.Name` is the username in question.  `User.IsInRole("taxpayer")` returned false. Below when I run the aspnet_db stored proc, it indicates the user in the list returned.....

```
USE [aspnetdb]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRoles]
        @ApplicationName = N'/',
        @RoleName = N'taxpayer'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

So now I'm wondering if it is a data issue.  Any thoughts???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user accessing the page is either not authenticated or not a member of the given role (your second option is the one I use) then they will be redirected to the authentication page. This is a filter, not a grant.

Comment: my test user is in the role, and when I use ` [Authorize(Roles="taxpayer")]` I log in, and just keep getting back to the login screen.

Comment: Double check it as I use this structure extensively without issue.

Comment: @Lazarus this caused the desired results, but makes no sense.  `[Authorize(Roles="")]`

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain - That's going to be semantically the same as `[Authorize]`, i.e. the user just needs to be authenticated. Create a new role, add your user to it, alter your `Authorize` attribute accordingly and restart your site, let's make sure there's no rogue elements floating about here. I use this (as do many others) in a production site that's been running for well over a year without issue, works exactly as you might imagine.

Comment: I would add that I haven't done this on the Home Controller nor would I imagine that you'd want to. Have you tried limiting the authorization to the methods you want to secure rather than the whole Home Controller?

Comment: @Lazarus - The problem was in the webconfig.  For whatever reason by default the file contains `<roleManager enabled="false">` I changed this to `<roleManager enabled="true">` and now everything is working correctly.

Comment: @Doug Chamberlain - Now that's a curve-ball, I don't recall having to change that but I've been working on the same MVC site for 1.5 years now so it's possible that in the dim (and it is dim) and distance past I did. Really pleased that you found a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

The second method

```
[Authorize(Roles="myrolename")]
```

is correct. If the user doesn't have that role, the behavior is to prompt them to login w/ a role that does have access.  If you want to change that behavior, you'll have to roll your own Authorize filter.